# How do I see exactly what my git push will do with a single command?

Tags: git

I currently do `git push -n`, and then copy and paste the commits listed into `git diff`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to know which commits would be pushed to on branch `master` to remote `origin` (i.e. `git push origin master:master`) you can use the following command:

```
git diff origin/master master
```

if `origin/master` is configured as upstream for `master` you can even write `master@{u}..{master}`.

rinse and repeat for each of your branches

---

remember that git push will copy all your commits to origin, and not just “one big diff”, so you're probably better off using `git log -p` instead of diff, to see each commit with its respective patch